# HTTP POST does not return expected JSON response

Tags: json, http, blackberry, java-me

I have pasted a code snippet for HTTP Post where I am POSTING a multipart message to the server which needs Authentication. I am expecting a JSON response, but when I run this I always get the login page in HTML.

```
public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen {
 private RichTextField _Output;
 public MyScreen() {
 // Set the displayed title of the screen
 setTitle("MyTitle");
 _Output = new RichTextField();
 add(_Output);
 addMenuItem(_GetDataAction);
}


 protected MenuItem _GetDataAction = new MenuItem("GetData", 100000, 10) {
 public void run() {
  String URL = "<Sample URL Goes Here>";
  ServiceRequestThread svc = new ServiceRequestThread(URL,
  (MyScreen) UiApplication.getUiApplication()
   .getActiveScreen());
  svc.start();
  }
 };


   public void updateDestination(final String text) {
  UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
  _Output.setText(text);
   }
    });
    }
    }


   class ServiceRequestThread extends Thread {
   protected String _URL;
   protected MyScreen _Dest = null;
   protected URLEncodedPostData _PostData = null;
   StringBuffer writer = new StringBuffer();
   public void setPOSTData(URLEncodedPostData data) {
   _PostData = data;
    }
    public ServiceRequestThread(String URL, MyScreen screen) {
    super();
    _Dest = screen;
    _URL = URL;
     }
        public void run() {

         try
         {
    String boundary = "SATBA";
     String twoHyphens = "--";
     String data1 = "{\"IMPORTING\":{ \"IN_COUNTRY_CODE\":\"US\"}}";
     String CRLF = "\r\n";
    byte[] encoded = Base64OutputStream.encode
    ("User:password".getBytes(), 0, "User:password".length(), false,false);

    "Prepare the data for post"

     writer.append("--" + boundary).append(CRLF);
     writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"param\"").append(
     CRLF);
     writer.append("Content-Type: text/json; charset=" + "UTF-8").append(CRLF);
     writer.append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit").append(CRLF);
     writer.append("Request-Id:Abcd123456" ).append(CRLF);
     writer.append("Request-Type:rfc_json").append(CRLF);
     writer.append("function:00163E0136C01EE0AE8B059433A71727")
     .append(CRLF);
      writer.append(CRLF);
     writer.append(data1).append(CRLF);
      writer.append("--" + boundary + "--").append(CRLF);
     String string = new String(writer);

    HttpConnection conn1 = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(_URL,Connector.READ_WRITE);
   conn1.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
  conn1.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+ new String(encoded));
  conn1.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","multipart/mixed; boundary=" + boundary);

   OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(conn1.openOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
   osw.write(string);
   osw.flush();
   osw.close();

   int responseCode = conn1.getResponseCode();
   if (responseCode == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {
   InputStream data = conn1.openInputStream();
   StringBuffer raw = new StringBuffer();
   byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
   int nRead = data.read(buf);
   while (nRead > 0) {
   raw.append(new String(buf, 0, nRead));
   nRead = data.read(buf);
    }
   _Dest.updateDestination(raw.toString());
    } else {
   _Dest.updateDestination("responseCode="
   + Integer.toString(responseCode));
     }
    }
     catch( IOException e)
       {
    e.printStackTrace();
   _Dest.updateDestination("Exception:"+e.toString());
    }
     }
            }
```

Comment: Without telling us the actual URL (for *most* urls, a HTTP response is expected and normal), you can't expect us to help.  At least tell us what the page reply is supposed to look like, and what kind of request its provider claims will elicit the JSON response you want.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply:) I am expecting a JSON RESPONSE like  below {\"EXPORTING\":{ \"OUT_CATEGORY_DISCRIPTION[]\":\"SALES\"}}";

Comment: i believe there is an issue in url.i once faced the same issue coz of the url or may be post request is not properly sent.have a look

Comment: I'm with Swati on this, probably an incorrect URL.

Comment: do u get entire html page in response or just some text like "text/html" and then followed your expected json response?

Comment: Thanks very much the code was perfectly alright and the issue was on the rim.public property file where the

application.handler.http.AuthenticationSupport was set to true and becuase of this it was not loggging in.

Now i set it to false and correct response came.

 

Thanks very much.

 

Best Regards

MGR
....

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the code was perfectly alright and the issue was on the `rim.public` property file where the `application.handler.http.AuthenticationSupport` was set to `true` and because of this it was not loggging in.

Now I set it to `false` and get the correct response.

Comment: Please don't post an answer to just thank somebody for the right answer. Use the comment feature instead to comment on the right answer and upvote/mark it as the right answer :)

Comment: @bjorn - that is an answer, a self answer.